# File not visible to partner in Code Together extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

I downloaded the CodeTogether extension and installed it in my VS Code all good till here. But when I start the code sharing and shared the link with my partner, He should see my code but the folder appears to be blank on his side and nothing is seen.

*Note: CodeTogether is an extension where people host their IDE with a sharable link. The partner opens the link in a browser and code together.*

[image]

As seen in the above image the partner can't see any files in the Instagram folder.

Comment: I know this answer comes too late, but we fixed a number of issues in a release a couple of weeks ago. If you still experience problems, one of the best ways to get support is to hit us up on Gitter https://gitter.im/CodeTogether-com/community